# Avoid polling and long running lambda task

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a cloudwatch group that monitors the number of times my application is started. Then I wrote a lamba function that should one every 24 hours in python retrieving these logs using boto3. To do this, I start a query and then polls the get_query_results method to see if it is finished. However, this leaves me with a pretty bad implementation that uses a lot of resources.

Is there a better way to perhaps use some kind of callback to do this?

These are the two functions I'm using
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.start_query

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.get_query_results

```
query_id = cloudwatch_connector.start_query('fields @timestamp, @message|filter @message like /APPSTART/').get('queryId')

# Wait until it is completed
running = True
while running:
    response = cloudwatch_connector.get_query_results(query_id)
    status = response.get('status')
    if status == 'Complete':
        print("Done gathering logs")
        print(response)
        running = False
    if status == 'Failed' or status == 'Cancelled':
        raise Exception('Request either failed or was cancelled')
    time.sleep(1000)
```

What I really wanna do is running a Insights query and saving it to a text file every night at 00:00